# Viewport and Media Queries are not matching values

Tags: css

I have an HTML/CSS/JS project.

In my `<head>` tag, I have this viewport `<meta>` tag:

```
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
```

In my CSS file, I have two media queries that are firing at values that are unexpected. I have defined the media queries with `max-width`, yet the changes in the UI are happening at different viewports, as described below in the comments:

```
/* actually happening between 320px and 561px */
@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .sidebar {
    border: 1px solid orange;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
  }

  main {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
}

/* actually happening when the screen is <= 320px */
@media only screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  .sidebar {
    border: 1px solid green;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    text-align: center;
  }
}
```

Does anyone know why this could be happening and how I could make the changes happen where I would like them (at `max-width: 700px` and `max-width: 400px`, respectively )?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) using the `<>` icon.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: This looks like there is some browser zooming happening. Try to reset the browser zoom to 100%

Comment: Brilliant! Yes, that was the issue. Resetting the browser to 100% makes the media queries make sense once again. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Also you can be more precise with using "new CSS media query range syntax" :
https://css-tricks.com/the-new-css-media-query-range-syntax/

Like that :

```
@media (400px <= width <= 700px) {
  .sidebar {
    border: 1px solid orange;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
  }

  main {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
}

@media (0px <= width <= 400px) {
  .sidebar {
    border: 1px solid green;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    text-align: center;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove initial-scale=1:

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
```

when you do so, you allow the browser to handle the scaling,
which might result in a more accurate interpretation of your media queries.

Use min-width instead of max-width

```css
/* Change at or above 700px */
@media only screen and (min-width: 701px) {
  /* Styles */
}

/* Change at or above 400px */
@media only screen and (min-width: 401px) {
  /* Styles */
}
```

it's a lot easier when you think of `max-width` and `min-width` as "less than" and "greater than".

*Hope you find this helpfull!*